# Can't fix Chrome developer mode

Tags: html, google-chrome, web

The thing is, I always have a bug, where the chrome's window for looking the way website works in the mobile vesion, jut gets broken. I get a weird vertical scroll, that should't be. How to fix that? I used to reload page, but now it doesn't fix the problem. Plus, I think about changing my search engine to duckduckgo and change the browser.

**How do I fix that?**

**If I cant, what browser should I use instead?**

[the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMBVN.png)

Comment: Your problem is not clear. How does a search engine relate to your problem? And how does the duckduckgo search engine solve your problem? Give more details, pls. Perhaps you just didn't include the viewport meta tag? - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: everything is ok in another browser.
The problem was, I opened mobile mode, and for some reason chrome did zoom the picture (impossible to unzoom. Just horizontal and vertical scrollbars appeared), which was done regarless to my actions, and only way to fix, was to refresh the page.

In another browser, it always worked right.